# What is the Japanese word for some kind of a technical diary for a machine (＝機械)"?

Tags: words, word-requests

I am looking for the Japanese word, meaning some **technical diary** for different types of machine, as for example a cutting machine or gluing machine, or a machine making frames, etc.

This diary contains information **mainly about the repairs made**. It can also include information about problems which occurred with the machine, which is waiting to be resolved. There are sometimes some technical information about these machines, but not always. This type of diary is necessary for every machine, being used in a factory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This diary contains information mainly about the repairs made.

At the machinery manufacturer I used to work for, we called it 「修理履歴{しゅうりりれき}」 or 「修理日誌{しゅうりにっし}」, and IIRC, we used the former more often.

FYI, the kind of diary that the workers kept mainly about what they produced daily was called 「作業日誌{さぎょうにっし}」 or 「加工{かこう}日誌」.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you very much for your precious answer and the extra info!!